# Many to one relationship sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I am a new user of MySQL and want to know how to create a realtionship between nurses and patients. There are 2 Nurses who take care of 6 patients how do i do that.

Table:

```
Nurses (id,name,lastname);
insert into Nurses (1,X,X);
insert into Nurses (2,X,X);

Patients (id,name,lastname);
insert into Patients (1,x,x);
insert into Patients (2,x,x);
insert into Patients (3,x,x);
insert into Patients (4,x,x);
insert into Patients (5,x,x);
insert into Patients (6,x,x);
```

How to create a realtion between these two? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a *junction* table:

```
create table PatientNurses (
    PatientNurseId int auto_increment primary key,
    PatientId int,
    NurseId int
);
```

This does not enforce the two nurses per patient condition.  For that, you can use a trigger or application level logic.

Comment: could i use char instead of int?

Comment: @VigKilla . . . Not for an auto-incremented column.